# How to find the largest, 2nd, 4th, 8th...2^logn th largest element in an array, use O(n) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection, big-o

Is there an O(n)-time algorithm to find the largest, second-largest, fourth-largest, ..., 2<sup>k</sup>th-largest, etc. elements in an array?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question with no additional explanation of how you're stuck or what you've tried.

Comment: Please specify whether the input array may be modified or copied (space O(n) is good enough).

Answer (score 4):

Since this looks like a homework question, I won't give a full answer. However, here are a few helpful hints:

1. Do you know how to find the kth largest element in an array in time O(n)? If not, you probably need to look this up before you're going to make any progress.
2. 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>log n</sup> = 2n - 1, which is O(n).
3. Use the algorithm from part (1) on intelligently-chosen arrays. The summation from (2) will help you prove that you have the runtime bound you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Find the kth largest element in an array in time O(n) can be done by using quickSelect, which gives the kth smallest element. But i'm not sure how to proceed from here. This is my first computer science class after c++ back in college long time ago..

Comment: @KKKKK As a hint, try using that algorithm as a subroutine on appropriately-chosen arrays.